# Using SoftwareSerial for the serial monitor

Tags: serial, softwareserial

Most programs follow this route: They have a `Serial.begin()` for the serial connection between PC and Arduino (the serial monitor) and they use SoftwareSerial for a device.

Can you go the other way around? Can you use SoftwareSerial for the communication between PC and Arduino, and Serial for a device?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: no.

Pins 0 and 1 an an Uno are directly wired to the PC communication chip. You could make a board that was wired differently and connected SoftwareSerial to the PC, but you would have to switch it back to pins 0 and 1 when uploading to the arduino somehow.

On an arduino leonardo "Serial" for communicating with PC over USB is different from "Serial1", which is connected to pins 0 and 1 on the board. You can use both simultaneously, so if you really need to use hardware serial and PC comms at the same time, I recommend you buy a leonardo.

Comment: But of course, you can omit the communication with the pc and have the hardware serial dedicated for communication with a device correct? And use the softwareserial for communicatoin with another device.

Comment: Yes that is correct, If you don't communicate with the PC hardware serial can be used for anything you please, and at the same time as Software Serial.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. If you use a USB FTDI type cable to connect your computer to the SoftwareSerial pins, you can use a terminal emulator program (HyperTerm, putty, etc) to communicate with the Arduino.